# which measure of central tendency might be used by the boss who is against a pay rise for other employees?

Tags: statistics

In an office of 20 people ther are only 4 salary levels paid :
50 000 (1 person), 42 000 (3 people), 35 000 (6 people), 28 000 (10 people).

I calculate the mean = 33300, the median = 30000 (usd).

But I am not sure which measure of central tendency might be used by the boss who is against a pay rise for other employees. Help me, many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The median of $30,000$ is more convincing because the people who are making $28000$ are only $2,000$ below the median while the rest of them are making much higher than the median.

Thus more people feel good about their salary if compared with the median than comparing their salary with the mean.